# How to get account name or list of accounts from a public key using eosjs? Account is on Jungle testnet

Tags: eosjs, account-name, testnet

```
    const { Api, JsonRpc } = require('eosjs');
    const fetch = require('node-fetch'); 
    const rpc = new JsonRpc('https://api.jungle.alohaeos.com:443', { fetch });

    let validAccounts =await rpc.history_get_key_accounts(pubkey)
    console.log(validAccounts)
```

I'm getting output as: { account_names: [] } But the account does exist for the public key.

Are there any api endpoints of jungle bloks to get the accountname from public key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'll need to work with a node that has the history API plugin enabled, try using this: `https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com`.

**Note:** The history API plugin is deprecated, so do take into consideration this API might stop working.

Comment: Thank you. So, is there any other way to validate account, other than history plugin?

Comment: https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com is not working.

Comment: 'https://lightapi.eosgeneva.io/api/key/<publicKey>' this is working.

Answer (score 0):

'https://lightapi.eosgeneva.io/api/key/' this history API plugin for  jungle testnet is working.